# Where can i find the Ui Path studio Activities Documentation guidelines?

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

Is there any full documentation of UI path All activities List slike it is available for Qliksense in terms of PDF?

Answer (score 1):

UiPath Studio includes by default the following activities packages as dependecies for all newly created projects:

- UiPath.Excel.Activities
- UiPath.Mail.Activities
- UiPath.System.Activities
- UiPath.UIAutomation.Activities

For any other activity you need to install corresponding packages in your UiPath project using Nuget Package Manager in UiPath Studio. You can find details documentation of all the activity packages in [Uipath official documentation portal](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/introduction) . For any particular activity like PDF activities you can check at corresponding section [UiPath.PDF.Activities](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/about-the-pdf-activities-pack).

Answer (score 0):

Overall it's not clear what you especially want to know!

But you should definitly check out the [UiPath Academy](https://academy.uipath.com/learn) first. But if you want a fast introduction to PDFs only you can check the [**Docs about PDF**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/read-pdf-files).

Also there is a good tutorial about PDFs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2-bWVBetvM).